# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: asp.net, image, user-controls

I created a user control with an Image. I use a repetear to created dinamically this user control.

I added a virtual folder to access to the path an get all the file to show the images.

But when I checked the page retrieve the nex below error:

[image]
The file names I retrieve using the virtual path called "Imagenes", that why is working well. I not assigend fixed path to retrieve the files names. But when I assigned to the ImageUrl to the image in the user control, retrieve the error. In the web form doesn't appear the images.

The web site in the IIS is like this with the virtual folder:

[image]

The folder have files, that's why I get the files names dinamically.

Thi is the path application, and the frm_VerifyIdentity is from where I put the user control to get the values.

[image]

Adtitionally I have this screen error of the folder:

[image]

I added user IUSR to the folder and nothing.

Comment: Where is the page that the images are on. Is the relative path correct?

Comment: I'm using a virtual path where the images are. And yes, is correct.

Comment: Have you tried opening that image path in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I retrieve the HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error